# Combine inline form with labels on top of input controls

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zb4dc/500/

That the labels are on top of the input fields is OK!

But I additionally want that each form-group is horizontally inline.

How can I do that?

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputfield1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Input 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputfield1" placeholder="Input 1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputfield2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Input 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2 controls">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputfield2" placeholder="Input 2">
        <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputfield3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Input 3</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputfield3" placeholder="Input 3">
    </div>
  </div>      
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you have to switch your `.form-group` div to `display:inline-block` and give it the correct width;

using non standard bootstrap class you can add this to CSS:

```
 .form-group{
   width: 30%;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 15px;
   float: left;
}
```

you could also use something like `col-sm-4` for a three column grid...

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/zb4dc/505/)

Comment: Thanks for fiddle. Why does input1 still line-break the textbox when I am on a high width like col-lg-* ? http://jsfiddle.net/zb4dc/516/ Any idea?

Comment: @Pascal is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/zb4dc/518/) the issue you want to get fixed ? (@ min-width: 768px you have bootstrap bringing in new styles that are altering the label styles )

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem.

[image]

Please have a look at this jsfiddle : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/imtiazahmed/pxv7m10f/2/)

```
.form-inline .form-group > div.col-xs-8 {
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
}
```

```
<legend>Form legend</legend>

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="inputfield1" class="col-xs-4">Input 1</label>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputfield1" placeholder="Input 1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="inputfield2" class="col-xs-4">Input 2</label>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputfield2" placeholder="Input 2">
    <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="inputfield3" class="col-xs-4">Input 3</label>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputfield3" placeholder="Input 3">
  </div>
</div>
```